# How to drop extra copy of duplicate index of Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series `s` with duplicate index :

```
>>> s
STK_ID  RPT_Date
600809  20061231    demo_str
        20070331    demo_str
        20070630    demo_str
        20070930    demo_str
        20071231    demo_str
        20060331    demo_str
        20060630    demo_str
        20060930    demo_str
        20061231    demo_str
        20070331    demo_str
        20070630    demo_str
Name: STK_Name, Length: 11
```

And I just want to keep the unique rows and only one copy of the duplicate rows by:

```
s[s.index.unique()]
```

`Pandas 0.10.1.dev-f7f7e13`  give the below error msg

```
>>> s[s.index.unique()]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "d:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 515, in __getitem__
    return self._get_with(key)
  File "d:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 558, in _get_with
    return self.reindex(key)
  File "d:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2361, in reindex
    level=level, limit=limit)
  File "d:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 2063, in reindex
    limit=limit)
  File "d:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 2021, in get_indexer
    raise Exception('Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index '
Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
>>>
```

So how to drop extra duplicate rows of series, keep the unique rows and only one copy of the duplicate rows in an efficient way ? (better in one line)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can groupby the index and apply a function that returns one value per index group.  Here, I take the first value:

```
In [1]: s = Series(range(10), index=[1,2,2,2,5,6,7,7,7,8])

In [2]: s
Out[2]:
1    0
2    1
2    2
2    3
5    4
6    5
7    6
7    7
7    8
8    9

In [3]: s.groupby(s.index).first()
Out[3]:
1    0
2    1
5    4
6    5
7    6
8    9
```

**UPDATE**

Addressing BigBug's comment about crashing when passing a MultiIndex to Series.groupby():

```
In [1]: s
Out[1]:
STK_ID  RPT_Date
600809  20061231    demo
        20070331    demo
        20070630    demo
        20070331    demo

In [2]: s.reset_index().groupby(s.index.names).first()
Out[2]:
                    0
STK_ID RPT_Date
600809 20061231  demo
       20070331  demo
       20070630  demo
```

Comment: It'd be great to know why this works.  The docstring for Series.groupby doesn't say anything about passing an index.  What's going on behind the scenes?

Comment: You can groupby an arbitrary list e.g. `s.groupby([1]*5+[2]*5).count()`, agreed docstring not hugely clear.

Comment: +1 for your answer, however something like `drop_publicates` for the index would be nice in pandas.

Comment: hayden, does the arbitrary list have to have the same length as the series index?  When I do `s.groupby([1, 2])` I get the error: `TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable'.`  What conditions need to be met when passing a list?

Comment: @Zelazny7 sorry, "arbitrary" of length len(s) :). I'm kind of guessing here, since I can't find it in the source...

Comment: @Zelazny7 Can you check 's.groupby(s.index).first()' for MultiIndex Series ?  Below is my snippet : import pandas as pd; idx_tp = [('600809', '20061231'), ('600809', '20070331'), ('600809', '20070630'), ('600809', '20070331')]; dt = ['demo','demo','demo','demo']; idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(idx_tp,names = ['STK_ID','RPT_Date']); s = pd.Series(dt,index=idx); # s.groupby(s.index).first() will crash on my machine

Comment: @bigbug passing a MultiIndex to series.groupby and then applying a function also crashed for me. I have updated my answer with a work around.  Hopefully a pandas developer can show a best-practice way of deduping a Series by passing an index.

Comment: @Zelazny7 's.reset_index().groupby(s.index.names).first()' works for me. It solve my headache. Thanks. But I somewhat dislike this for it involves reset_index, groupby, first to solve looks like simple filter issue ,don't know whether cause performance penalty.  (Might Set operation make it simple ?). I raise a issue at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2706

Comment: This worked for me on a df using last() as well. But I agree that it's a lot of steps: a `drop_duplicates` for the index would be very helpful.

Answer (score 14):

You could subset your data with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) (which keeps first value by default) for `index`. With @Zelazny7 example:

```
s = pd.Series(range(10), index=[1,2,2,2,5,6,7,7,7,8])

In [130]: s[~s.index.duplicated()]
Out[130]: 
1    0
2    1
5    4
6    5
7    6
8    9
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This should be the answer

Answer (score 7):

One way would be using `drop` and `index.get_duplicates`:

```
In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
                      String
STK_ID RPT_Date             
600809 20061231  demo_string
       20070331  demo_string
       20070630  demo_string
       20070930  demo_string
       20071231  demo_string
       20060331  demo_string
       20060630  demo_string
       20060930  demo_string
       20061231  demo_string
       20070331  demo_string
       20070630  demo_string

In [44]: df.drop(df.index.get_duplicates())
Out[44]: 
                      String
STK_ID RPT_Date             
600809 20070930  demo_string
       20071231  demo_string
       20060331  demo_string
       20060630  demo_string
       20060930  demo_string
```

Comment: Sorry, i should have made my intention more clearly. What I want is : keep the unique rows and only one copy of the duplicate rows. Not totally drop the duplicated ones. I modified the question accordingly.

Comment: I think that drops all of the duplicates, even the first occurrence.

Comment: @bigbug I think the answer by Zelazny7 is more appropriate in this case. I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

What about?

```
s.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=s.index.names).set_index(s.index.names)
```

For example, for `s`:

```
STK_ID  RPT_Date
600809  20061231    demo_str
        20070331    demo_str
        20070630    demo_str
        20070930    demo_str
        20071231    demo_str
        20060331    demo_str
        20060630    demo_str
        20060930    demo_str
        20061231    demo_str
        20070331    demo_str
        20070630    demo_str
dtype: object
```

```
s.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset=s.index.names).set_index(s.index.names)
```

```
                           0
STK_ID  RPT_Date    
600809  20061231    demo_str
        20070331    demo_str
        20070630    demo_str
        20070930    demo_str
        20071231    demo_str
        20060331    demo_str
        20060630    demo_str
        20060930    demo_str
```